# Is there a way to stop android services in init.rc gracefully (without SIGKILL)?

Tags: android, linux, service, signals, init

I have a native Android service that is started and stopped by a property set via the GUI. 
The commands to start and stop the service in init.rc are as follows:

```
service myservice /system/bin/myservice
    class late_start
    user my_service
    disabled

on property:persist.myapp.myservice.enable=1
    start myservice

on property:persist.myapp.myservice.enable=0
    stop myservice
```

There are JNI memory resources that need to be cleaned up if the service is stopped, but it appears that the service is stopped via a SIGKILL:

```
6944  6974 V myservice: IMyProcessA::onTransact()
 712   712 I AP_KERNEL: init: Service 'myservice' is being killed...
 510   510 I ServiceManager: service 'ProcessA.MyService' died
 656   656 V ProcessA: ProcessA::NotificationClient::binderDied()
 656   656 V ProcessA: removeNotificationClient() 0xb6bc60a8, pid 6944
 656   656 V ProcessA: ProcessA::NotificationClient::~NotificationClient()
 712   712 I AP_KERNEL: init: Service 'myservice' (pid 6944) killed by signal 9
 712   712 I AP_KERNEL: init: Service 'myservice' (pid 6944) killing any children in process group
```

Since there is no way to intercept a SIGKILL to clean up, are there any options for the init.rc 'stop myservice' that can change the termination signal to something I can intercept like SIGTERM, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this with a coworker, our consensus was that after a SIGKILL, the kernel would reclaim all of the memory associated with the process and that there would be no memory leak.

If anyone has any information contradicting that, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your "no memory leak" stands on kernel side, but many works need to be done in user space before one process ends, such as the following,

- close files and flush cached data into kernel layer.
- delete some temporary files.
- notify other process that I am about to die.
- write some data caching in RAM to disk, or the data on DISK will inconsistent.

......
For the above, sending SIGKILL is very crude.